# Spotify OAuth 2.0 callback python

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, request, spotify

I'm following the spotify documentation to authenticate through the WEB API .... with the code below I can get the access authorization

```
import requests

endpoint_auth = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/spotify/index.html'
client_id = '1234567890'
scope = "playlist-modify-private"

params_auth = {
        "response_type": "code",
        "client_id": client_id,
        "scope": scope,
        "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
}

response_auth = requests.get(url=endpoint_auth, params=params_auth)
print(response_auth.status_code)
print(response_auth.text)
```

first print is all ok response 200 the second print give me the content of page html for login if i save the content inside a doc html and open the file give an error but if I compose the url path and launch it from the browser like "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=1234567890&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/spotify/index.html&scope=playlist-modify-private" the response send me in my callback page (http://localhost:8888/spotify/index.html?code=23u2344u123u4u1) and add a CODE parameter to the url in get.... this is a parameter to request the access token.

My question is: There is a possibility to read the url callback after I have made the request so like i print response_auth.text print the callback url with parameter code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the requests_oauthlib Library which manages it, see https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/spotify.html

```
#First set the client_id/client_secret/redirect_uri
#authorization_base_url, token_url & scope

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
spotify = OAuth2Session(client_id, scope=scope, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

# Redirect user to Spotify for authorization
authorization_url, state = spotify.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
print('Please go here and authorize: ', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('\n\nPaste the full redirect URL here: ')
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)

# Fetch the access token
token = spotify.fetch_token(token_url, auth=auth,
authorization_response=redirect_response)
print(token)

# Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
r = spotify.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me')
print(r.content)
```